# How run Opencl T-API in opencv 3.0 beta.?

Tags: c++, opencl, opencv3.0

I am exploring OpenCl with OpenCV.

I am working sample face detection code using Opencv 3.0 beta. I wrote code with Opencl T-API as proposed in opencv 3.0 beta.

What did i do :

1. Built **openCV 3.0** with **opencl + Mingw.**
2. But i didn't install or refer any other supporting packages.
3. As per Opencv 3.0 beta version, the **Opencl T-API** code works on **both CPU and GPU**.If recommanded Opencl Version available,then code will work on Opencl(GPU).
4. When i test the code (http://pastebin.com/bLSjvjzv ) , I got the message **Opencl is "ON"**, But i did **not get any improvement** in-terms of FPS.

Am i doing any thing wrong any where?

Comment: Could anyone help me to run basic opencl T.API code with Opencv 3.0 beta.?

Comment: Also check if you are using the right device, you might be running on the integrated GPU instead of your dedicated one thus getting no real improvement.